# Integrating Spring and Hibernate 3. Application throws exception when creating the beans

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Good afternoon! I'm starting studies with Dependency Injection and Inversion of Control with data persistence using the frameworks Spring and Hibernate.  I'm trying to integrate the two using Spring to control the Hibernate SessionFactory for all components monitored by Spring can receive as dependence SessionFactory, Spring controlling everything.Unfortunately I am not able to accomplish this goal, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'produtosController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private br.com.caelum.estoque.dao.ProdutoDAO br.com.caelum.estoque.controller.ProdutosController.produtoDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'produtoHibernateDAO' defined in file [C:\Program Files\eclipse\apache-tomcat-8.0.15\wtpwebapps\fj27-projeto-spring\WEB-INF\classes\br\com\caelum\estoque\dao\ProdutoHibernateDAO.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: : Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to instantiate default tuplizer [org.hibernate.tuple.entity.PojoEntityTuplizer]
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:298)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1148)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934)
org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:602)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:521)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:462)
org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

From what he says can not create the bean to the "SessionFactory" and thus can not create the beans for persistence of data, "DAOS". I'm a week with this problem, I have seen and reviewed the settings in the app-config.xml, tried many things, I tried the forum but nothing I tried worked, now I'm asking for your help.

Here are my project files:

ProdutosController

```
    package br.com.caelum.estoque.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import br.com.caelum.estoque.dao.ProdutoDAO;
import br.com.caelum.estoque.model.Produto;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "produtos")
public class ProdutosController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("produtoHibernateDAO")
    private ProdutoDAO produtoDAO;

    @RequestMapping(value = "index")
    public String index() {
        return "produtos/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "listar", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listar() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("produtos/lista");
        modelAndView.addObject(produtoDAO.listar());
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "mostrar/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView mostrar(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("produtos/mostrar");
        modelAndView.addObject(produtoDAO.buscarPorId(id));
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "form")
    public String form() {
        return "produtos/form";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "salvar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String salvar(Produto produto) {
        produtoDAO.salvar(produto);     
        return "redirect:/produtos/listar";
    }
}
```

ProdutoHibernateDAO

```
package br.com.caelum.estoque.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import br.com.caelum.estoque.model.Produto;

@Repository
public class ProdutoHibernateDAO implements ProdutoDAO {

    private Session session;

    @Autowired
    public ProdutoHibernateDAO(SessionFactory factory) {
        session = factory.openSession();
    }

    public void salvar(Produto produto) {
        session.save(produto);
    }

    public void alterar(Produto produto) {
        session.update(produto);
    }

    public List<Produto> listar() {
        List<Produto> produtos = session.createQuery("from Produto").list();
        return produtos;
    }

    public Produto buscarPorId(Long id) {
        return (Produto) session.get(Produto.class, id);
    }
}
```

ProdutoDAO

```
package br.com.caelum.estoque.dao;

import java.util.List;

import br.com.caelum.estoque.model.Produto;

public interface ProdutoDAO {

    void salvar(Produto produto);
    void alterar(Produto produto);
    List<Produto> listar();
    Produto buscarPorId(Long id);
}
```

Produto

```
package br.com.caelum.estoque.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Produto {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    private String descricao;
    private Integer quantidade;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public Integer getQuantidade() {
        return quantidade;
    }

    public void setQuantidade(Integer quantidade) {
        this.quantidade = quantidade;
    }
}
```

app-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">


    <!-- Configura aonde o Spring deve buscar por beans anotados -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.caelum.estoque" />

    <!-- Habilitar suporte a anotação @Controller -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Factory Bean para a SessionFactory do Hibernate. Utilizando esta factory 
        fazemos com que a SessionFactory do hibernate seja gerenciada pelo Spring. -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/fj21" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="m19731973f" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Configuração das propriedades do Hibernate -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" value="dataSource" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/fj21</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">root</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">m19731973f</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>br.com.caelum.estoque.model.Produto</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <display-name>FJ27 Estoque</display-name>

    <!-- Configura o Spring Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                    /WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml
                </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

aplicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

</beans>
```

I tried to change the constructor method like this

```
@Autowired
public ProdutoHibernateDAO(SessionFactory factory) {
    session = factory.getCurrentSession();
}
```

and methods

```
public void salvar(Produto produto) {
    session.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().save(produto);
}
```

The jars both spring and hibernate are in version 4.

Comment: I'm not certain what the issue is, though it looks like a classpath problem. If you're starting out, is there a reason you're using old versions instead of Spring 4.1 with Spring Boot and Hibernate 4?

Comment: When a spring application context is started,  it logs the names of all beans that it knows. Find this log and add it to your question.

Comment: BTW : the way you handle hibernate session in the dao is not correct. You should use sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() in all your CRUD methods.

Comment: @chrylis I was using hibernate and sspring 3, updated jars to version 4 but not resolved.

Comment: @MaartenWinkels Where i found this log? On the console?

Comment: @MaartenWinkels I tried to use this way of handling methods but had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I changed both the jarss Spring as the Hibernate to version 4 (spring 4.1.4.RELEASE, hibernate 4.3.8.Final). So I changed my app-config.xml file and let him thus:

```
<!-- Configuração das propriedades do Hibernate -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/fj21</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">root</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">m19731973f</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>br.com.caelum.estoque.model.Produto</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

I think there should be a version conflict of jars. Now is working perfectly.
Thanks for everyone's help.